# nodejs async.forEach callback was already called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I'm using the `async` library to help me with my control flow. I have a collection over which I want to iterate, for each element execute 1 asynchronous task and when all are done, call the callback.

I've decided to use an `async.forEach` loop, on each loop I call my asynchronous task but I get an error: `callback was already called`, but shouldn't the callback be called only when all callbacks are called? And I even wanted to understand properly how to handle errors, it is highly probable that some task will fail and others will succeed, I don't need to know which elements fail, but I would like, how can I do this?

This is my code:

```
async.forEach(fonts, function(font, callback) {
    ftpm_module.installOsFont(font, callback);
}, function() {
    console.log("finished");
});
```

EDIT: the error occurs only if I pass 2 or more fonts.

Comment: Can you show the insights of your `ftpm_module.installOsFont`? It seems like the given callback in there gets called twice.

Comment: the `callback` has to be run on finish of the iteration. That is your `ftpm_module.installOsFont` has to contain `callback();` in the end, and only once.

Comment: @alandrev ftpm_module.installOsFont is asynchronous, I tried putting callback(); after the function but. but the calblack gets called before the installOsFont finishes the execution.

Comment: @charminbear I wanted to put a pastebing url with the function, but for how the code is written it's easier if you go on the github repo wich is: https://github.com/alanmastro/ftpm-module, you can find the function in the ftpm-module.js file, wich calls a series of event in lib/ftpm.js

Comment: @Charminbear I just checked to be sure, but the installOsFont emits the callbacks correctly.

Comment: Can you for sake of testing change the code to: `async.forEach(fonts, function(font, callback) {
    callback();
}, function() {
    console.log("finished");
});` If it works, then you know issue is in ftpm_module

Comment: ok, it worked fine, so you say I can be sure the problem is in ftpm_module?

Comment: it really dosn't seem to be an issue of ftpm_module, or if it is so it's really hard to find, I'm trying passing 2 fonts each time, and as a result of [this](http://pastebin.com/KtETmeQz) code I get that the callback is beeing called 2 times for 2 fonts, is that correct? it makes sense to me.

Comment: I just realized something: The async-lib doesnt have a `forEach`-Function. Which async-lib are you using, are you using any plugins and did you mabye intend to use the `each()`-Function?

Comment: I finded the forEach function in [link](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice) tutorial. I'm not getting any error from function taht don't exist, and the each functions dosn't it make a callback at the end of every single task?

Comment: The current version of `async` has an `each` method rather than `forEach` (though I suspect you would get a completely different error if that was the root cause of the problem here).

Comment: @jcaron I think so to!

Comment: Try to replace the `ftpm_module.installOsFont(font, callback);` with `ftpm_module.installOsFont(font, function() { console.log("callback called",font); callback(); });`. This will show you how many times the callback is called for each font.

Comment: Also, are you sure you get the error during this loop, and not later? ftpmModule saves the callback, so if you make further calls later on that may call a callback but don't give them one, they may call the callback you previously gave.

Comment: @jcaron I tried you code and it prints 2 times the name of the last font I gave in the n(event with n != 2) element array. I'm not sure if I understood your second callback, you say I shouldn't pass 2 times the callback to ftpmModule? how could I do this?

Comment: I tried using forEachSeries and works perfectly... it's not a problem to use forEachSeries, but I would like to use forEach,

Comment: Can you be more explicit as to what the results of the test are for 2 or 3 fonts? For 2 fonts, is it (a) #1, #2, #2 or (b) #2, #2? Ditto for 3, is it (a) #1, #2, #3, #3 or (b) something else?

Comment: My impression is that the problem is in ftpm_module: instead of passing the callback along, it saves the callback as a module-scoped variable, so on the second (and subsequent) calls, the callback gets overwritten, and the first call doesn't call the first callback, but a later one.

Comment: I took a quick look around in [ftpm-module](https://github.com/alanmastro/ftpm-module/) and it looks like if there's an error when looking for a font, it'll emit the error twice: once in [searchInstalledFont](https://github.com/alanmastro/ftpm-module/blob/aab0237b8fc2faa82712623b7c61b6cad1d18e57/lib/driver/osfont.js#L33) and once in [install](https://github.com/alanmastro/ftpm-module/blob/aab0237b8fc2faa82712623b7c61b6cad1d18e57/lib/driver/osfont.js#L67).

Comment: thank you! I'll try and fix the error in ftpm-module.